# How to Block IIS Hit From browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I'm making a API Web service,
How can I block the HTTP requests from browser?

Also, how can I block continues request from same IP ?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stack overflow. In order for your question to be answered quickly and properly, you need to show the code you have tried already. Check this <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask'> link </a> for info on how to ask a question.

Comment: Is not clear what you want to do...do you want to block the request at application level? May be hooking up to the webapi pipeline? Try to be more exhaustive